# How to block torrents (GUFW) and secure the block

Tags: bittorrent, parental-controls, p2p

The question is related to the aggressive-materials free machine. Currently, I am secured by pluckeye software but struggling with access to torrents.
I would like to block all torrent traffic, secure the block with a password but keep my su privilege (ie to be able to install new software etc) - it should be different password.
Currently, I use GUFW to block torrent traffic - it is working fine. But I can access GUFW anytime and just unblock the traffic when I hit the "bad time".

Is there any way to prevent myself to access GUFW?
Any other way to block torrent traffic and secure it without losing the admin modes would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the torrent client?

Comment: I can reinstall the client anytime. The point is to prevent me from being able to do so.

Comment: You are the boss. You can do what you want. Make someone else the only person with sudo powers. Only the boss can stop you!

Comment: There are many "*Make the system stop me from doing X*" questions here already. Your Ubuntu system is not designed to be responsible for your actions.

Comment: Ok cool, time to change the system apparently. Many thanks, experts, problem solved.